# C++11 why is the move constructor called before returning a temporary object

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm studying C++11 and I don't understand why in the following code

```
class X
{
    std::vector<double> data;
public:
    // Constructor1
    X():
        data(100000) // lots of data
    {}

    // Constructor2
    X(X const& other): // copy constructor
        data(other.data)   // duplicate all that data
    {}

    // Constructor3
    X(X&& other):  // move constructor
        data(std::move(other.data)) // move the data: no copies
    {}

    X& operator=(X const& other) // copy-assignment
    {
        data=other.data; // copy all the data
        return *this;
    }

    X& operator=(X && other) // move-assignment
    {
        data=std::move(other.data); // move the data: no copies
        return *this;
    }

};

X make_x() // build an X with some data
{
    X myNewObject; // Constructor1 gets called here
    // fill data..
    return myNewObject; // Constructor3 gets called here
}


int main()
{
    X x1;
    X x2(x1); // copy
    X x3(std::move(x1)); // move: x1 no longer has any data

    x1=make_x(); // return value is an rvalue, so move rather than copy
}
```

in the line

```
return myNewObject; // Constructor3 gets called here
```

the Constructor3 gets called. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X make_x() // build an X with some data
{
    X myNewObject; // Constructor1 gets called here
    // fill data..
    return myNewObject; // Constructor3 gets called here
}
```

`myNewObject` gets destroyed at the end of this function scope, so its ok for the compiler to rip its guts out with a move.

Comment: There are two operations, 1. Copying/Moving the local object `myNewObject` and 2. Assigning it to `x1` by copy/move assignment. Most likely the copy/move constructor call will be completely elided and only move assignment operator will be called.

Comment: Just checked and [Gcc does actually elide the move constructor call](http://ideone.com/g8Br60)

Comment: @AlokSave and if you call `make_x()` in an initialization like `X x2=make_x()`, it will be constructed in its final place, [modified example here](http://ideone.com/o4ALB2). This shows that nowadays even big objects can be used efficiently without references/pointers, thanks to C++11 move and efficient copy elision.

Comment: @Piotr99: True, move semantics do provide a huge potential for performance sensitive programs, but your peculiar example does not demonstrate that power. It merely demonstrates the power of compiler to optimize by applying copy elision. Your very same example with C++03 will [produce the same result](http://ideone.com/P3AEwQ).The difference being in C++03 you rely on power of compiler to optimize while with C++11 the standard provides a means to provide optimizations regardless of capability of the compiler.

Comment: @AlokSave well, as I included your part with the move-assignment, my example illustrates both the efficiency of move and of copy elision.

Answer (score 3):

You see a move construction because your compiler is not doing all the optimization that it is permitted to by the standard.

Nominally, the variable `myNewObject` is move-constructed to the temporary that is the return value of `make_x`, and then the temporary is move-assigned to `x1`. This is what you're seeing.

However, in this case the standard permits something called "move constructor elision". It's basically the same thing as "copy constructor elision", which might be familiar to you from C++03. It means that the variable `myNewObject` and the temporary that is the return value of `make_x` can be transformed by the compiler into a single object. That leaves just the move assignment.

Apparently your compiler has not done the move elision.

If you expected a copy, then the reason it's a move is that in C++11, a return value that is eligible for copy elision (which this one is), is explicitly required to be moved rather than copied where a move is available. I can't remember the reference, and don't have the standard on hand, so you'll just have to take my word for it.